# Loop is longer than my list - how to know where I land?

Tags: python, list, loops, return, iteration

apologies if this has been asked before but I went over the different questions and maybe because I am new I couldn't understand the solutions. I will try to give my specific problem and hopefully someone can help clarify.

**What I have:**

list = ['a','b','c','d','e']

n = 17

**What I want to do**

I need to loop through (n) elements in my list, where n > len(list)
How to know where the loop will stop?

example:

list = ['a','b','c','d','e']

n = 3

the returned value will be 'c' (the 3rd element in the list)

Thank you very much for any help,
f3rzli

Comment: Use dictionaries instead !

Comment: Wait...your example defies your problem statement: you say "I need to loop through (n) elements in my list, where n > len(list)", but your example has `n < len(list)` (3 < 5).

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: Sorry I gave the example of n=3 to say when it's shorter than the list, it's easy to determine which index the loop stops. But my issue is that when n is longer than the list, how to go back to index zero and continue counting.

Comment: Did my answer answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *modulus* (`%`) operator.

Following your example, if you do:

```py
>>> L = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> n = 3
>>> L[n % len(L) - 1]
'c'
```

> Since Python is zero-indented, to get your list item you should subtract `1` (the third element of the list has position `2`)

If I understood correctly, `n=8`, for example, should give the same result as `n=3`:

```py
>>> N = 8
>>> L = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> i = N % len(L) - 1
>>> L[i]
'c'
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to iterate the list to get the nth element, you can use 'list[n]' to get that. But if you need to iterate the list based on indexes, you can do that in the following way.

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','e']
for i in range(0,n):
    if i==n:
         a = l[i]

print(a)
```